# What does "jealous of that in each other" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does this sentence mean? I once again examined entries for "jealous" but to no avail (maybe I didn't know something about that word, I thought). It just doesn't make any sense to me

> Often a man wishes to be alone and a girl wishes to be alone too and if they love each other they are jealous of that in each other, but I can truly say we never felt that.

[*from Chapter 34 of *A Farewell to Arms* by Ernest Hemingway]

According to the standard usage of "jealous", it should be followed by "of" and then a thing one of two people doesn't have but wants to. With that in mind, what is "that" in "jealous of that"?

Comment: Sergey, it's the same as the Russian word "ревновать"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of jealousy involves being insecure about whether your partner is going to stay with you. So if you find out that your partner wants to be alone sometimes, it could make you jealous, even though you feel the same thing yourself.

"Jealous" has more than one meaning. Here, it's a combination of these two from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jealous), and not the meaning similar to "envious":

> **2 a :** intolerant of rivalry or unfaithfulness
> **b :** disposed to suspect rivalry or unfaithfulness

Normally, when we use this meaning of "jealous", we don't include "of", but here, there's a particular thing that triggers the feeling of jealousy, and Hemingway chose to use the preposition "of" to connect it. It's not standard.

Comment: According to the standard usage of "jealous", it should be followed by "of" and then a thing one of two people doesn't have but wants to. With that in mind, what is "it" in "jealous of it"?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev it's the enjoyment of being alone.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I think Hemingway is using "jealous of" in a slightly non-standard way here. The meaning without "of" seems more natural here, even if this is non-standard.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev I've updated my answer

Comment: I'm afraid this answer seems to be completely wrong.  The meaning of jealousy is completely clear and normal.  OP is asking *what* it is they are jealous of.

Answer (score 5):

You could be called jealous if you feared that your partner's love of their own company were a rival to their love of you.

(This extends the sense of being jealous of another person who is able to steal your partner's attention.)

Comment: I knew a guy whose girlfriend was jealous of his mother, his sister, and his cello.

Comment: The correct answer. What is the boy jealous of?  The boy is jealous "of the girl herself".  Who is getting the attention of the girl?  Well - "the girl" is getting the attention of the girl.  So he's jealous of "the girl".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey double-lol  :) But it probably just confuses the OP.

Comment: So by "jealous of that" he meant "jealous of their partner's wish to be alone because of their partner, as if their partner's wish to be alone was their rival for their partner's attention"? 

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Yup. The practical takeaway is: Each lover wanted more of the other's attention, including the time they spent alone. So they were jealous of that time (they envied it, they coveted it, they wanted it).

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Often a man wishes to be alone and a girl wishes to be alone too and if they love each other they are jealous of that in each other, but I can truly say we never felt that.

The man is jealous of the girl wanting to be *not with him* at times. The girl is jealous of the man wanting to spend time *not with her* at times.

That both would be spending time alone rather than with each other is not all that much different than if they wanted to spend time with someone else, even non-romantically. For, in both cases, they don't spend the time *together*. And if being together is what they yearn, the alternatives may well induce jelousy for the time "taken away" from each other.

Comment: -1 this might sound plausible, but note that in the novel, the next thing that the "man and woman" (although Hemingway uses the term "girl") **do** is spend the night alone **together**.  There is no hint of the man resenting any time the girl spends apart from him, and whatever the meaning of this jealousy, the man says that they never had it.

Comment: Hemingway is describing a hypothetical situation: "often" here is a way to introduce an example. He quickly states that the example doesn't apply to him, though.

Answer (score -1):

Ther words "jealous" and "jealousy"  have several senses. Probably the most common in current usage is romantic or sexual jealousy, where a person fears that a romantic or sexual partner will leave, or prove unfaithful, or that a potential partner will choose someone else. But I do not think thqt such a sense is being used in the Hemingway quote in the question. The quote said:

> if they love each other they are jealous of that in each other, ...

But what is the "*that*" which the narrator says they are jealous of? The word "*that*" here refers back to th earlier phrase:

> Often a man wishes to be alone and a girl wishes to be alone too ...

I think this refers not to the man and woman being aparty from one another, but to their being **alone together**, and in particular to their having privacy to engage in sex or sexual and affectionate acts, such as kissing and caressing each other. Note, that is what the couple in the story actually do. So when the speaker says that they are "*they are jealous of that*" I think it means jealous in the sense of "unwilling to share", that such a couple resents people or circumstances that prevent or restrict hjeiort having time alone together.

Hemingway's style of writing puts things in a somewhat different way than other writers do, as here where he writes

> Often a man wishes to be alone and a girl wishes to be alone too ...

rather than something like:

> Often a man and a woman wish to spend time alone together...

A longer versiuon of the quote is:

> That night at the hotel, in our room with the long empty hall outside and our shoes outside the door, a thick carpet on the floor of the room, outside the windows the rain failing and in the room light and pleasant and cheerful, then the light out and it exciting with smooth sheets and the bed comfortable, feeling that we had come home, feeling no longer alone, waking in the night to find the other one there, and not gone away; all other things were unreal. We slept when we were tired and if we woke the other one woke too so one
> was not alone. **Often a man wishes to be alone and a girl wishes to be alone too and if they love each other they are jealous of that in each other**, but I can truly say we never felt that. We could feel alone when we were together, alone against the others. It has only happened to me like that once. I have been alone while I was with many girls and that is the way that you can be most lonely. But W'e were never lonely and never afraid when we were together. I know that the night is not the same as the day: that all things are different, that the things of the night cannot be explained in the
> day, because they do not then exist, and the night can be a dreadful time for lonely people once their loneliness
> has started. But with Catherine there w^as almost no difference in the night except that it was an even better time.

I think that the sentence:

> We could feel alone when we were together, alone against the others.

makes it clear that Hemingway is not, in this passage, writing about his characters being by themselves, or fearing being without each other.

Comment: Nah, he's just saying:  "Sometimes she wanted to be alone. But that didn't bother me at all."

Answer (score -2):

It's extremely badly written.

Hemingway at his best is "concise" and "profound sounding".  But he often crosses over to sentences that are confused nonsense.

> what is "it" in "jealous of it"

The "it" is "aloneness" or "herself".

The girl wants to be alone with "aloneness".  Or you could say the girl wants to be alone "with herself".

The boy is jealous of "aloneness", or, "herself".

Let's say I said to you

> "I want to be with myself for an hour."

You might reply humorously

> "Oh, that makes me jealous of 'yourself', it seems that 'yourself' will get to spend an hour with you, I wish I could be 'yourself'."

### Here's a "translation" to plain modern writing:

> "Sometimes, a boy wants to be alone. Usually, that makes the girl really annoyed. Sometimes, a girl wants to be alone. Usually, that makes the boy really annoyed. However, in our case, we were both completely happy about it, when, the other person wanted some alone-time."

That's all he's trying to say here.

Comment: lol downvote ...

Comment: -1 I do not think the antecedent of "that" in the  passage can be reasonably be said to be "aloneness" nor that the "modern translation" is a plausible rendering. In particular;r I do not see anything meaning "that makes the boy really annoyed". The passage says  "***they** are jealous of that*", not "he".

Comment: jealous and annoyed are the same thing.  the downvotes are laughable in this case.

Comment: While "Jealous" & "annoyed" both indicate negative emotions, in my view they are not close to "the same thing", Nor was that the prime reason for my downvote. But [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jealous) gives being "hostile", "intolerant", and "vigilant" in its def of "jealous" while in its [def of "annoyed"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annoyed) it gives "feeling or showing **angry irritation**". "Annoyance" is used for a much less intense emotion. But the main problem with the "translation" is that the assumption that "alone" here means apart from each other